# How to enable c++17 on vscode(MAC)

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++17

I am currently using vscode on mac.

when using pair on .cpp file, the error message comes; 
error: a space is required between consecutive right angle
      brackets (use '> >')

on doing g++ -std=c++17 -g filename.cpp, error never comes out. But using g++ filename.cpp however, can't use this templates.

I can't even try tuple so have trouble working on it.

my current c_cpp_properties.json is like this;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeCiT.png)

and my launch.json is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4iQc.png)

and lastly my tasks.json is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujh5F.png)

How can i use g++ filename.cpp without those warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two consecutive `>` to close out nested template declarations is not legal in C++98/03, but is legal in C++11 (and later).

Your command `g++ filename.cpp` is (presumably) defaulting to C++98, while when you try `g++ -std=c++17 -g filename.cpp` you are expressly indicating that you want to compile for C++17.

Comment: How can i change default compiler then..? Should i upgrade  g++ compiler by terminal?

Comment: @김준희 you can make a Makefile in the folder where you run your code from, like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41521862/1615620

Answer (score 0):

Click on the bottom right button that says C++ (File type is automatically detected by vscode otherwise you have to select Language Mode for the file) and select Configure 'C++' language-based settings... - it will open settings.json file

Change field "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard" to "c++17"

Answer (score 0):

To compile on the command line I used the following command - note here I am using Apple clang version 12.0.0

clang some_file.cpp -std=c++11 -lstdc++

In my vscode editor I added no changes and do not need any spaces between consecutive '>'.